# Convert list of irregular length tuples to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I have a list with ~5 million elements in which list element represents an observation, which can take 10 separate values. These are stored as tuples that look something like this:

```
[(0, 0.23411436),
 (1, 0.011154618),
 (2, 0.32306415),
 (3, 0.011153304),
 (4, 0.011153304),
 (5, 0.011153304),
 (6, 0.011153304),
 (7, 0.36474636),
 (8, 0.011153304),
 (9, 0.011154029)]
```

I'd like to convert this a pandas dataframe where the first value in each tuple is a column, and the second value is the entry for that column. The problem is that the model that generated these values suppresses values < 0.01, so some tuple entries look something like this:

```
[(0, 0.23411436),
 (1, 0.011154618),
 (3, 0.011153304),
 (4, 0.011153304),
 (5, 0.011153304),
 (7, 0.36474636),
 (9, 0.011154029)]
```

How can this be converted to a dataframe, replacing omitted values with zero?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "The problem is that the model that generated these values suppresses values > 0.01"

Comment: @bug_spray Whoops, that should be < 0.01. I'll edit that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one line like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(lst), dict(short_lst)]).fillna(0)
```

Here is the full example:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [(0, 0.23411436),
     (1, 0.011154618),
     (2, 0.32306415),
     (3, 0.011153304),
     (4, 0.011153304),
     (5, 0.011153304),
     (6, 0.011153304),
     (7, 0.36474636),
     (8, 0.011153304),
     (9, 0.011154029)]

short_lst = [(0, 0.23411436),
             (1, 0.011154618),
             (3, 0.011153304),
             (4, 0.011153304),
             (5, 0.011153304),
             (7, 0.36474636),
             (9, 0.011154029)]

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(lst), dict(short_lst)]).fillna(0)
print(df.to_string())
#           0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
# 0  0.234114  0.011155  0.323064  0.011153  0.011153  0.011153  0.011153  0.364746  0.011153  0.011154
# 1  0.234114  0.011155  0.000000  0.011153  0.011153  0.011153  0.000000  0.364746  0.000000  0.011154
```

Comment: Thanks! Very simple, elegant solution.